# Max rows listview xamarin

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a list view that displays a ladder of points on a sports team and am trying to only show the top 5 players. Is there anyway that this can be in XAML?

Thanks,

Ryan

EDIT: Here is my code

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MIApp.PlayerPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout Margin="20,0,0,0" Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Label Text="Player Info" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
            <Grid MinimumHeightRequest="200" RowSpacing="10" Padding="0">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Label Text="Goal Leaders" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="GoalListView" Grid.Row="1">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding StrFullName}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding IntGoals}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                    <Label Text="Point Leaders" Grid.Row="2" Margin="0"/>
                    <ListView x:Name="PointListView" HasUnevenRows="true" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,0,0,0">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0" Spacing="0" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                            <Label Text="{Binding StrFullName}" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                            <Label Text="{Binding IntPoints}" HorizontalOptions="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
            </Grid>
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class PlayerPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PlayerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected async override void OnAppearing()
        {
            base.OnAppearing();

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            string urlGoals = "https://melbourneicewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Player_Info/GetPlayer_Info?playerInfo=goals";
            string urlPoints = "https://melbourneicewebapi.azurewebsites.net/api/Player_Info/GetPlayer_Info?playerInfo=points";
            var responseGoals = await client.GetAsync(urlGoals);
            var responsePoints = await client.GetAsync(urlPoints);

            if (responsePoints.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                string resGoals = "";
                using (HttpContent contentGoals = responseGoals.Content)
                {
                    Task<string> resultGoals = contentGoals.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    resGoals = resultGoals.Result;
                    var GoalsList = Players.PlayersItems.FromJson(resGoals);
                    GoalListView.ItemsSource = GoalsList;
                }
                string resPoints = "";
                using (HttpContent contentPoints = responsePoints.Content)
                {
                    Task<string> resultPoints = contentPoints.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    resPoints = resultPoints.Result;
                    var PointsList = Players.PlayersItems.FromJson(resPoints);
                    PointListView.ItemsSource = PointsList;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Connection Error", "Please Connect to the internet and try again", "Ok");
            }
        }
    }
```

Players Class where objects are created from JSON string and added into a list:

```
public class Players
    {
        public partial class PlayersItems
        {
            [JsonProperty("$id")]
            public long Id { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intPlayerID")]
            public int IntPlayerId { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strFirstName")]
            public string StrFirstName { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strSurname")]
            public string StrSurname { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intGamesPlayed")]
            public int IntGamesPlayed { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("strPosition")]
            public string StrPosition { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intPlayerNumber")]
            public int IntPlayerNumber { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intGoals")]
            public int IntGoals { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intAssists")]
            public int IntAssists { get; set; }

            [JsonProperty("intPoints")]
            public int IntPoints { get; set; }

            public string StrFullName {
                get
                {
                    return StrFirstName.Trim() + " " + StrSurname.Trim();
                }
            }

        }

        public partial class PlayersItems
        {
            public static List<PlayersItems> FromJson(string json)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<PlayersItems>>(json);
            }
        }
    }
```

So what I am essentially doing is accessing an API that gives me two JSON Strings of all the data entries in the Players Table,One that is sorted by highest points, the other by highest goals, it is then converted into a list of objects from the Players Class, and then set to the appropriate List View.

Comment: purely in XAML?  Not that I'm aware of, but you can easily use LINQ to filter your ItemsSource to only show the needed data.

Comment: The answer is of course you can. However, you need to show your code, we have no idea how you have structured your app, whether you are using MVVM, whether this is all done in code, or what your structure looks like to answer anything more

Comment: Sorry @Saruman, just added it now. I'm not currently using an MVVM model though, its just pretty basic. I'm pretty new to Xamarin so I'm not to comfortable the MVVM Model atm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use LINQ to select the top X scores before assigning them to ItemsSource.  I'm not aware of any way to filter the data directly in XAML

```
var PointsList = Players.PlayersItems.FromJson(resPoints);

var topPoints = PointsList.OrderByDescending(x => x.PointsInt).Take(5).ToList();

PointListView.ItemsSource = topPoints;
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys! It did the trick. Can i just ask while we're here, i'm trying to display the names and the values on the same line, for some reason with the XAML above it displays a gap vertically, is there a way i can get around this?

Comment: you are using a Vertical StackLayout.  If you want them side by side, use a Horizontal StackLayout